# ineffable cardinals has a stationary subset of inaccessibles

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

**Definition** : a cardinal is called ineffable if for every sequence of sets $\left<A_\alpha\ \big|\ \alpha<\kappa\right>$ s.t $A_\alpha \subset\alpha$ there is a set $B\subset\kappa$ s.t

$$S=\left\{\alpha<\kappa\ \bigg|\ B\cap\alpha=A_\alpha\right\}$$

is stationary.

I want to show that I can assume that $S$ contains only strong inaccessible cardinals. I have trouble showing that there is even a strong inaccessible below $\kappa$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Another quick way to see that there are many inaccessibles below $\kappa$ is to prove first that $\kappa$ is inaccessible, and then show $\kappa$ is $\Pi^1_2$-indescribable. So therefore $\kappa$ is weakly compact and the set of weakly compact cardinals is unbounded in $\kappa$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The previous proof has a critical error.*

First, I claim that every ineffable cardinal $\kappa$ is inaccessible. By definition, we assume that $\kappa$ is regular. Thus it suffices to show that $\kappa$ is a strong limit.

Assume the contrary that there is $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $2^\lambda\ge\kappa$. Let $\langle A_\alpha\mid \alpha<\kappa\rangle$ be $\kappa$ distinct subsets of $\lambda$. (We may assume that $A_\alpha\subseteq\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.)
Take $B$ such that $S=\{\alpha<\kappa\mid B\cap \alpha = A_\alpha\}$ is stationary. Then the sequence
$$\langle A_\alpha\mid \alpha\in S\rangle$$
is a strictly increasing $\kappa$-sequence of subsets of $\lambda$, but such a sequence cannot exist: consider the sequence $\beta_\xi=\min(A_{\xi'}\setminus A_\xi)$ for $\xi \in S$, where $\xi'$ is the next element of $\xi$ in $S$.

Now we will prove the main problem:
For each $\langle A_\alpha \mid\alpha<\kappa\rangle$, take $\overline{A}_\alpha$ such that
$\overline{A}_\alpha=A_\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is regular, and choose any cofinal subset of $\alpha$ of ordertype $\operatorname{cf}\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is not regular.

Let $B\subseteq \kappa$ be such that $S=\{\alpha<\kappa\mid B\cap \alpha = \overline{A}_\alpha\}$ is stationary. We claim that the set $\overline{S}$ of all regular cardinals in $S$ is stationary. If it holds, then by the inaccessibility of $\kappa$, the set of all strong limit cardinals $C$ is a club. Hence $\overline{S}\cap C$ is the desired set.

Assume the contrary that $\overline{S}$ is non-stationary. Then $S\setminus \overline{S}$ is stationary, and its elements are non-regular cardinals. Now consider the function $f:S\setminus \overline{S}\to\kappa$ defined by $f(\alpha)=\operatorname{cf}\alpha$. Then $f$ is regressive, so there is a stationary $T\subseteq S\setminus \overline{S}$ such that $f\upharpoonright T$ is constant with value, say, $\gamma$.

Note that for every $\alpha\in T$, $\alpha\cap B$ is a cofinal subset of ordertype $\gamma$. Hence $\langle \alpha\cap B\mid \alpha\in T\rangle$ forms a strictly increasing sequence of subsets, all of them has ordertype $\gamma$, which is impossible since $\alpha\cap B$ is an initial segment of $\beta\cap B$ if $\alpha<\beta$.

---

References

1. J.E. Baumgartner, *Ineffability properties of cardinals I* in Colloquium Mathematica Societatis János Bolyai 10, Infinite and finite sets I (1973).

Comment: But why is the set of all strong limit cardinals below $\kappa$ is a club?

Comment: @ItamarShmelo The main reason is that $\kappa$ is inaccessible: unboundedness of $C$ follows from the inaccessibility of $\kappa$, and a limit of strong limit cardinals is also strong limit in general.

Comment: What I dont understand is why $\kappa$ cant be the first strongly inaccessible cardinal

Comment: @ItamarShmelo The quick way to explain it is that my proof works, so the first inaccessible cardinal cannot be ineffable. (But you won't like this explanation.) It would be better if I give some counterexample, but I am running out of time. I will try it after hours.

Comment: Also why is "$A_\alpha\neq\emptyset$ for some regular $\alpha$, then $B$ must be non-empty" neccessarily true?

Comment: @ItamarShmelo It is an error but seems easily mendable. I will fix it.

Comment: @ItamarShmelo There was a non-trivial gap in my previous proof. I fixed it, and I hope it works fine.